# Convexity increases the "cost" of long steps

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $V(n)$ be a non-decreasing, convex function on $\mathbb{N}$ such that $V(0)=0$, $V(1)=1$.
Let $(r_i)_{i=1}^{N}$ and $(r^{\prime}_i)_{i=1}^{N^{\prime}}$, $N^{\prime} > N$, be two sequences of positive integers such that $\sum\limits^N_{i=1} r_i = \sum\limits^{N^{\prime}}_{i=1} r^{\prime}_i = L$, for a fixed constant $L$.

Prove that,
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} V(r_i) \geq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N^{\prime}} V(r^{\prime}_i),
$$
i.e., if we interpret $V(n)$ as the ''cost'' required for performing a jump of length $n$, the previous expression tells us that convexity of the cost function implies that it is always more convenient to perform "small" than "large" jumps to cover a given distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to show is false.

The first problem is how to interpret convexity of a function defined on the natural numbers. Normally you want the domain of a convex function to be convex. Here, I will assume that you mean that $V$ can be extended to a convex, non-decreasing function on all of $[0,\infty)$. Any other interpretation I can think of will be weaker than this.

Now, let $V(x)=x^2$, which fulfilfs your assumptions (with the above interpretation). Fix $M$ and let $L=2N+2$. Consider the partitions

$$
L = 1+1+2N= (N+1) + (N+1). 
$$

If what you want was true, we would have
$$
4N^2 +2= 1^2 + 1^2 + (2N)^2 \leq (N+1)^2 + (N+1)^2 = 2N^2 + 4N + 2,
$$
which clearly fails for large $N$.

A similar consideration using the partition

$$
L = (2N+2) = (N+1) + (N+1)
$$

shows that the reverse inequality (i.e. your claim with "$\leq$" replaced by "$\geq$") also fails.

Comment: I think that the condition that I needed in order the statement to be true is that, for each $[r^{\prime}_i, r^{\prime}_{i+1}]$, there exists and $i$ such that $[r^{\prime}_i, r^{\prime}_{i+1}] \subset [r_i, r_{i+1}] $.

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm: Could be, I will think about it. But it would probably be a good idea to create a new (modified) question.

Comment: A related question...

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383894/least-expensive-way-to-walk-with-a-convex-potential