# Least expensive way to "walk" with a convex potential

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $V(x)$ be a non-decreasing, convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$.
Fix some positive integers $L$ and $k \leq L$.
Let $A_{L,k}$ be the space whose elements are sequences of positive integers $r= (r_i)_{i=1}^{N}$ such that $L - \sum\limits^N_{i=1} r_i < k$ and all the $r_i \geq k$.

Prove (or disprove) that the minimum of 
$$
\mathcal{H}(r) := \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} V(r_i) 
$$
among the sequences $r \in A_{L,k}$ is attained by the sequences which have all $r_i =k$.

If we interpret $V(x)$ as the ''cost'' required for performing a jump of length $n$, the previous expression tells us that convexity of the cost function implies that it is always more convenient to perform "small" than "large" jumps to cover a given distance.

Comment: Looks like an interesting problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Two problems and a statement here. 1) we need to assume $k\geq 0$ or else $r_i$ is not in the domain of $V$. 2) We must also assume that $Nk\leq L$, or the problem is not feasible. 3) It is not clear to me why the specific values $V(0)=0$ and $V(1)=1$ are important. I believe the problem could probably be solved assuming convexity and monotonicity alone.

Comment: I modified the statement.

By convexity one could check that, if one takes two sequences, $r$, $r^{\prime}$ such that for every interval $[r_{i-1},  r_{i}]$ there exists a $j$ such that $[r_{i-1},  r_{i}] \subset [r^{\prime}_{j-1},  r^{\prime}_{j}]$, then $\mathcal{H}(r) \leq \mathcal{H}(r^{\prime})$. How to prove that the minimum is attained wen the jump lengths is the smallest as possible?

Comment: I'm actually not convinced this is right, BTW. Do you know it to be true, and you're looking to build the proof as an exercise? Or are you asking if it is true? In particular I do not believe $r_i=k$ necessarily.

Comment: Actually, you have an internal contradiction. it is not possible for one of the elements of $r$ to be less than or equal to $k$; such a sequence would not be in $A_{L,k}$.

Comment: I solved such a contradiction in the edit.

Comment: I imagine that it should be true but I would like to prove or disprove it.

Comment: $V(x)$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$ so isn't $V(k)\leq V(r_i)$ for each $i$, since $r_i\geq k$? Then the statement follows.

Comment: The changes here are significant enough that many of my comments do not apply.